# Freehand remover tool

Tags: canvas, toggle, openlayers

Is there a way to remove a freehand drawing from an open layers map, like a rubber?

I have searched through the tutorials and have not been able to find any mention of a way of remove a drawing other than refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

By removing, do you mean clearing the entire drawing or feature?

If you just want to clear the drawing you can use `source.clear()`

Else you could get the feature you want to remove by using select interaction and then remove it using `removeFeature()` method of `ol.source.Vector()`